# deja de funcionar en el servidor

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, jquery

Tengo un código que su función es agregar datos a la base de datos mediante ajax jquery, el detalle que local mente me funciona perfectamente sin nigua tipo de error al ejecutar, el detalle esta que al momento de subirlo al servidor y ejecuto el formulario para agregar los datos me marca el error que una de las variables va vacía, hago un console.log localmente de la variable y si trae datos, en el servidor va vacia, cual podria ser el error??...

```
$('#insert_datos_transporte').on("submit", function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var m_fecha;
    document.getElementById("tipo_embarque").value = document.getElementById("tipo").value;
    if (!document.getElementById("numero_embarque").value) {
        $.ajax({
            url: "include/function/agregar_embarque.php",
            method: "POST",
            data: {},
            dataType: "json",
            success: function(embarke) { //aqui marca el error de la variable no definida 
                embarque = embarke[0];
                m_fecha = embarke[1];
                document.getElementById("numero_embarque").value = embarke[0];
                $('#n_embarque').html(embarke[0]);
                $.ajax({
                    url: "include/function/actualizar_datos_camion.php",
                    method: "POST",
                    data: $('#insert_datos_transporte').serialize(),
                    beforeSend: function() {
                        $('#insertar').val("Actualizando");
                    },
                    success: function(data) {
                        console.log(data);
                        $('#insert_datos_transporte')[0].reset();
                        $('#datos_transporte').modal('hide');
                        racks_embarcar(embarque);
                        fecha_today();
                        $('#m_embarque').html(embarque);
                        $('#m_fecha').html(m_fecha);
                        $('#modal_agregar_racks').modal('show');
                        if (nivelUsuario == 2) // Consultas
                        {
                            document.getElementById('encabezado_busqueda').style.display = 'none';
                            $('#generar_caratula').hide();
                        } else {
                            document.getElementById('encabezado_busqueda').style.display = 'block';
                        }
                    }
                });

            }
        });
    } else {
        $.ajax({
            url: "include/function/actualizar_datos_camion.php",
            method: "POST",
            data: $('#insert_datos_transporte').serialize(),
            beforeSend: function() {
                $('#insertar').val("Actualizando");
            },
            success: function(data) {
                $('#insert_datos_transporte')[0].reset();
                $('#datos_transporte').modal('hide');
                location.reload();
            }
        });
    }
});
```

archivo de agregar_embarque.php

```
$connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "unidades"); 
    $query = "INSERT INTO embarques () VALUES ();";  
    $result = mysqli_query($connect, $query);
```

Comment: Puedes agregar un `console.log(embarke)` despues de `success: function(embarke) {` para revisar como trae el dato

Comment: se me paso agregarlo en este codigo pero si lo tengo y en el servidor viene como null y local me manda un objeto con los datos que estoy enviando en el formulario

Comment: Resultado del console.log(embarke)
{0: "10", 1: "2020-02-24 15:44:42", embarque: "10", fecha: "2020-02-24 15:44:42"} // respuesta local
en el servidor respuesta es null

Comment: Entonces el problema no es Javascript, sino la respuesta que está enviando PHP. Por favor edita tu pregunta y agrega el código de agregar_embarque.php

Comment: Tienes que verificar que estás dirigiendo la petición a la URL correcta aquí: `url: "include/function/agregar_embarque.php"` y verificar que todo está OK en el servidor: conexión a la base de datos, credenciales, versiones de la API de conexión, etc. Ayudaría mucho que revises el log de errores del servidor, ahí te dirá casi seguro qué es lo que está fallando y donde.

Comment: el error es de enrutamiento me sucede mas mucho, hasta que adquirí un servidor para hacer prueba, veras tienes que hacer la verificación de esta ruta ```include/function/agregar_embarque.php``` por lo general siempre marca error, amenos que le agreges ```www.sitioweb.com/include/function/agregar_embarque.php``` a la proxima te recomiendo usar un framework php para evitar eso tipos de error por ruta

Comment: el detalle que no tengo acceso como admin al administrador, es un servidor local que accedemos mediante su ip por ejemplo 10.14.57.130/mf/itc/index.php, el ejemplo de www.sitioweb.com/include/function/agregar_embarque.php no me funciona no me marca el error de la variable vacia pero me marca error en el jquery.